# Determining conversions with undeterministic data

Tags: data-visualization

Just a quick background on the process.

```
We get a lead -> O(1) -> We phone the lead -> O(n) -> Lead converts
```

- The frequency of leads we get is relative, but unnecessary for this statistic.
- We call the lead at O(1) time, and determine the impression.
- We receive something at O(n) time, this is a conversion.

The statistic we are creating is for the people who spoke to the leads.
If the lead converted, then the salesperson gets a point.  Simple enough.

Here is the tricky part, the number of leads the sales person spoke to counts "against" them, so the ratio is formed simple as:

```
conversion/impressions
```

In most sales instances, this is not an issue because the conversions and impression tend to happen within a relatively short period of time from one another.  Our problem is that this period of time is largely indeterministic, making it very difficult to fairly grade someone's performance.

For example, someone who made a lot of impressions today, but no conversions, can't be considered bad performance because they may convert tomorrow, next week, or next month.

Is there a fair and accurate (within reason) way to get this data?